# Facebook in-app login webapp

Tags: android, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

i'm making a webapp using phonegap for IOS and android.

In my web i've got a login form that uses facebook, i want, instead of open Facebook login in browser, login users by using the app Facebook.

i found this on GitHub, that seems be the official plugin by phone gap

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

when i try to install it by Macbook terminal i have this problem:

```
MBP-di-Andrea:Bparty Andre$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID=00000000 --variable APP_NAME=BParty
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin" via git clone
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c git clone "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin" "/var/folders/t3/bzvxk7td567_y58nl1nsclbw0000gp/T/git/1428503102506"
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
```

i have some question:
-how can i solve this problem?
-after installed phone gap, how do i use Facebook in-app login instead of browser?
-is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plugin for that purpose is the right method.
The problem you're having, is not directly connected to that specific plugin, but to your Xcode path.
Open your terminal and run:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

After that try to re-install the plugin.

Comment: ok, plugin installed, now how should i use it to log my users? @Asaf

Comment: Well the API is pretty straight forward. To login just call: facebookConnectPlugin.login(Array strings of permissions, Function success, Function failure).